# is there any possibility trigger sql in Mysql to increment year of study column

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a database in Mysql server with the tables. One of the tables is students table with column `year_of_study`.
Can I use the trigger to increment the column `year_of_study` by 1 in every new year of study which always starts in October

**student table structure**:

[image]

Comment: can you describe a use case where you'd need to increment the study year?

Comment: You rather just store the year someone started, never change that value and then, when querying the data, you calculate how many years have passed since then.

Comment: Do **not** post images of tables. Post the `CREATE` and `INSERT` statements necessary to create and populate them as **text**.

Comment: *Can i use the trigger to increment the column year_of_studet by 1 in every new years of study which is always start in October* Trigger? No. Use Event scheduler procedure.